# python mysql.connector execute() "%s"に文字列を渡すと余計な ' で囲まれる問題

Tags: python, mysql

## 状況

`foo`という名前のデータベースが作成したいです。
そこで、以下のスクリプトを実行しました。

## 実行スクリプト

```py
import mysql.connector

self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                user=XXXX,
                password=XXXX,
                host=XXXX
            )
self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

database='foo'
query = 'CREATE DATABASE `%s`;'
cur.execute(query, (database,))
```

## 結果

しかし、スクリプトを実行すると`'foo'`という名前のデータベースが作成されてしまいます。
executeメソッドによって`%s`に変数`database`が代入される際、意図せぬ`'`で文字列が囲まれてしまっているようです。

## 疑問

1. なぜ作成されるデータベース名が意図せぬ`'`で囲まれてしまうのか？
2. `'`で囲まれる現象を回避できるのか？

Comment: 2 に関しては `cur.execute(query, (database,))` を `cur.execute(query % database)` とすればシングルクォートが付くことはありません。